# VirtualBox VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I trying to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed VirtualBox from Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then I added my user to vboxusers:

```
sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a user
```

I also installed an extrapack for my vb version:

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129.vbox-extpack

sudo vboxmanage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.10-104061.vbox-extpack
```

But when I trying to start vm, I get an error:

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing  '/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime
what:  4
VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

And I have no `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` file.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've removed all the virtualbox packages:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge 'virtualbox*'
```

Then I've installed virtualbox v.5

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

After that I've enabled virtualization in BIOS.
Now it works.

Answer (score 12):

Check what version of virtualbox you installed

```bash
dpkg --list 'virtualbox*'
```

may be it's not aligned with the Extension pack.

Remove your installation

```bash
sudo apt-get autoremove 'virtualbox*'
```

Don't install from Ubuntu repositories but run a fresh installation following the instuctions from [official Oracle Virtualbox Download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) about Debian-based Linux distributions.

Check that Virtualbox is running before installing the Extension pack.

Comment: My case: I had mixed versions 6.1.2 but 5.2.34 for others, so: «sudo apt remove virtualbox-guest-utils» «sudo apt remove virtualbox-guest-x11» «sudo apt remove virtualbox-qt» and fixed! (THX!)

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. I had also mixed versions as a result of trying to install virtualbox via apt-get, and later installed it via the .deb from the official downloads.
Removing the older version and installing the downloaded .deb seemed to work fine

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error starting a vm client in ubuntu 16.4 .
[image: Error message]

Coincidentally I noticed in the file */var/crash/_usr_lib_virtualbox_VirtualBox.0.crash*  the following message:

> Title: VirtualBox crashed with SIGABRT in QMessageLogger::fatal()
>   UnreportableReason:  Sie haben einige veraltete Paketversionen
>   installiert. Bitte aktualisieren Sie die folgenen Pakete und prüfen
>   Sie, ob das Problem danach noch auftritt:
>
> virtualbox-dkms

Translated: *You have some outdated package versions installed. Please update the following packages and check, if the problem still occurs after that:*

After the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade virtualbox-dkms
```

all was OK :)

Comment: Really helpful, this was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have Virtualbox installed for minikube and the GUI app. After running the only upgrade and then running  `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` it was solved